# Problem with equation $u_{xx}+4u_{yy}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

**Given task:**

Find a solution to the boundary value problem in the domain $\left \{ x>0, y>0 \right \}$ in the class of bounded functions using the Fourier transform
$$u_{xx}+4u_{yy}=0, u|_{x=0}=\theta (2-y),u|_{y=0}=0$$

**My attempt:** I don’t know how to solve it, if the problem is in the boundary conditions, we won’t be able to solve it, there the boundary conditions contradict each other: $u(0;y)=\theta(2-y)$ and $u(x;0)=0$, accordingly $u(0;0)$ must be both $0$ and $1$

*Tell me how to solve this problem?*

Comment: What is the definition of theta you are using?

Comment: $\theta(y)$ - Heaviside step function.

Comment: With a half-infinite domain, it seems like a Laplace transform is more fitting.

Comment: We will not be able to find the inverse Laplace transform for our function. There you will have to expand the function into a Bessel series, which will not give a specific answer

Comment: You have no idea how much I struggled! With the Fourier transform, Laplace, Melin and even with simple methods. Everything led to special functions: elliptic or Bessel function or you could not take the inverse Laplace transform... It turns out it's a lot simpler than that! In order not to have a special function in the answer, you have to function.

Comment: Heaviside function must be removed immediately! I usually work with special functions and am not used to removing them, and always worked or one transformed through the other, and here I didn't even think about it... Behold the true beauty of this solution $$\theta (y-1)=\frac{1}{2}{left ( 1+\mathrm{sgn}(y-1) \right )$$ - with this simplification all integrals are taken easily, the Fourier transform is simple and the answer is expressed through elementary functions!